# JUnit test not sending values as parameters to function (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, junit, mockito, viewmodel

I am creating a simple junit test to test a function in my view model but the first assertion fails as the function I call returns null. When I debug the function I call has null parameters which is weird cause I pass them in.

I have spent time debugging and searching for why I am having that issue but I have found nothing that fixes my issue or tells me what the issue is.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner::class)
class CurrencyUnitTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @Mock
    val currencyViewModel : CurrencyViewModel = mock(CurrencyViewModel::class.java)

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)

        val rates: HashMap<String, Double> =
                hashMapOf(
                    "USD" to 1.323234,
                    "GBP" to 2.392394,
                    "AUD" to 0.328429,
                    "KWR" to 893.4833
                )

        val currencyRates = MutableLiveData<Resource<CurrencyRatesData?>>()
        val resource = Resource<CurrencyRatesData?>(Status.SUCCESS, CurrencyRatesData("CAD", rates, 0))
        currencyRates.value = resource

        `when`(currencyViewModel.currencyRatesData).thenReturn(currencyRates)

        val baseCurrency = MutableLiveData<String>()
        baseCurrency.value = "CAD"

        `when`(currencyViewModel.baseCurrency).thenReturn(baseCurrency)
    }

    @Test
    fun calculateValueTest() {
        // this fails
        assertEquals("0.36", currencyViewModel.calculateValue("AUD", "1.11"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mocked classes will not really be called. If you want to test your currencyViewModel.calculateValue() method, create a real object of that class and mock possible constructor arguments.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what Ben has said: the class you want to test has to be a real object, not a mock. A mock "does nothing" per default, and only does what you do it to tell you, so to test it does not make any sense.

What you mock is the dependencies of the class you test, i.e. the objects you pass to its' constructor.

In short: if you want to test `CurrencyViewModel`, create an object of it instead of mocking it.